# Is it possible to install mysqli extensions via docker run command

Tags: docker

I created a docker volume with index.php file.
Now, every time I run a new container I want to mount this file (I know how to do that), but what if I want to add `mysqli extension` to any new container,
Is it possible????

```
docker run -d -it -p 80:80 test --name=www1 --mount source=myvol1,destination=/var/www/html php:7.2.2-apache ----
docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this image's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/9e50ad06426e7de8213ec59ce96dbeab38266dfe/7.2/buster/apache/Dockerfile) & it's [entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.2/buster/apache/docker-php-entrypoint):

If you add command to install extension at the end of `docker run` which will act as `CMD` of entrypoint, it will make `apache2-foreground` has no chance to start.

So, the only way in runtime is:

**Step1: start the container**

```
docker run -d -it -p 80:80 --name=www1 --mount source=myvol1,destination=/var/www/html php:7.2.2-apache
```

**Step2: install extension with exec**

```
docker exec -it www1 docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

**Step3: restart the container:**

```
docker stop www1 && docker start www1
```

And in fact, the typical way to do this is to customize it in your own dockerfile, but it maybe not you want:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.2.2-apache
RUN xxx // install things as you like here
```

Comment: Welcome, if it help you, you could accept it, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's a bit later, but if someone were facing the same issue and don't want to use a Dockerfile here's how you can do it.

If you look at [php-apache's 7.2 Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/9e50ad06426e7de8213ec59ce96dbeab38266dfe/7.2/buster/apache/Dockerfile) where `CMD` is set you can find the `apache2-foreground` command.

You can just invoke the mysqli install command on `docker run` and append the `CMD` content like:

```
docker run -d -it -p 80:80 --name=www1 --mount source=myvol1,destination=/var/www/html php:7.2.2-apache sh -c 'docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli && apache2-foreground'
```

Doing that way the mysqli extension will be installed, loaded and the container entrypoint properly loaded.